# Jet.Com Bulk Upload error

Tags: java, file-upload, apache-commons-httpclient, http-put, jet.com-apis

I am integrating Jet.com with our Java based application.I am successfully able to upload the Merchant Sku bulk upload file,but in the Partner Dashboard it gives error "File Not Found".

Java API code:

```
      try {   

          String url = fileURL.get("url").toString().trim();
          String gzipFile = filePath + ".gz";
          FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(gzipFile);
        GZIPOutputStream gzipOS = new GZIPOutputStream(fos);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while((len=fis.read(buffer)) != -1){
            gzipOS.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        //close resources
        gzipOS.close();
        fos.close();
        fis.close();

          HttpPut request = new HttpPut(url);
          request.addHeader("x-ms-blob-type", "blockblob");

          FileEntity  entity = new FileEntity(new File(gzipFile));
          entity.setContentType(ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM.toString());
          entity.setContentEncoding("gzip");
          request.setEntity(entity);

          HttpResponse res = httpClient.execute(request);
          System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(res.getEntity()));
          return true;
    }
```

While viewing the uploaded file in Jet.com partner portal,it gives error "File not found". I guess the problem might be with HttpPut File upload code, but I am not sure.

[image]

Comment: Please do not add requests for urgency/ASAP etc to your questions, [read more here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569). Thanks.

Comment: What is the HTTP return code that jet.com is sending back?

Comment: Return code is 200 OK,if you check file is uploaded to Jet.com server but it gives out File not found error

Answer (score 0):

```html
{"SL-SBEC-32L":{"product_title":"Foldable Fabric Drawer Lagoon Blue","product_description":"Brighten up your home with a lagoon blue Foldable Fabric Drawer from Tidy Living. The bright blue drawer offers a convenient way to organize and sort small items like cords, keys, cooking utensils and more. The cube-style drawers are perfect for use with cube organizers, open shelving units and more. The fabric drawers feature an open top for easy access and versatility. A built-in fabric handle on the front makes the drawer easy to grip and easy to operate. Foldable Fabric Drawers from Tidy Living are a great addition to any home&rsquo;s decor and can even be used as a seasonal update. The medium cube organizers measure 10.5&rdquo; W x 10.5&rdquo; D x 11&rdquo; H and are the perfect size for most uses. Other colors of fabric drawers are also available including black, red, and brown.","brand":"Tidy Living","standard_product_codes":[{"standard_product_code":"849392007293","standard_product_code_type":"UPC"}],"mfr_part_number":"SL-SBEC-32L","jet_browse_node_id":13000263,"multipack_quantity":1,"main_image_url":"https:\/\/tidyliving.com\/pub\/media\/catalog\/product\/s\/l\/sl-sbec-32l_-_non-woven_fabric_foldable_fabric_drawer_-_blue_-_angle.jpg","alternate_images":[{"image_slot_id":1,"image_url":"https:\/\/tidyliving.com\/pub\/media\/catalog\/product\/s\/l\/sl-sbec-32l_-_non-woven_fabric_foldable_fabric_drawer_-_blue_-_sideways.jpg"},{"image_slot_id":2,"image_url":"https:\/\/tidyliving.com\/pub\/media\/catalog\/product\/s\/l\/sl-sbec-32l_-_non-woven_fabric_foldable_fabric_drawer_-_blue_-_front.jpg"}]}}
```

This is the json file, the file needs to be in a .json.gz format.

1. Please check the json.gz format is correct or not.
2. After that upload it to the url you get from "get url request.
3. Increase expiry time(in sec) if needed".
4. Check json.gz contain proper merchantsku json file.
   5.Check that Put request headers contain `x-ms-blob-type :blockblob`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which of the api you are using for bulk product upload,
if you are using

```
https://developer.jet.com/docs/testinput-1
```

Then your url should be like this:

```
https://prodimupload.blob.core.windows.net/merchant-files/ea74847dd3804e18a004233c4880e27b?sv=2015-04-05&sr=b&sig=6k2GN53DFdWSjFm%2BCA9nrA1i4nfGNVwmrYEzT%2FzVDPI%3D&se=2017-05-30T08%3A40%3A39Z&sp=w
```

which you will get when you call this api:

```
/files/uploadToken
```